# MVC: how should I switch between different datasets - update or replace?

Tags: java, swing, dataset

My Swing app is intended to collect, persist and display information that we care from log archive files generated by our benchmark test system.

Let's say the archive files are managed as `Project`s (according to the test case, etc) in my app. For now I designed the interface to have a JTree on the left that lists ProjectGroups and `Project`s, an information panel on the right which has an JFreeChart that shows a revision - score chart and a Table thats shows detailed information of the selected point on the chart.

When I select different `Project` node in the tree, I want the info panel to show the information of the selected `Project`.

So...

Question 1:

Should I create only one info panel no matter how many `Project`s I have, or one panel for each `Project`? ( now I would prefer only one panel )

Question 2 (If I choose only one panel):

The Chart has its model `Series`; the Table has its `TableModel` as well.
How should I deal with these models with my own `Project`s?
Should each `Project` hold its own `Series`, and then the app sets the Chart and Table to use a new Model when switching between `Project`s?
Or, should there be only one `Series`, and each time the switch happens, clean up the existing data in the `Series` and add the data from the new `Project`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal feeling would be to go with a single info pane.

When a use selects a project, I would pass the project reference to the info pane.

Here you have a number of options.

You could simply re-create the models from scratch or, if you prefer, cache the results, so when you switch projects, you simply pull the cached models out and apply them.

This will depend on the size of the data, the number of times it might change and the availability of memory.

If the dataset's are large or it changes often, for example, it might be better to re-create the model's each time the project selection is changed.

Comment: The data in the dataset only changes when the user clicks the "refresh" or "delete" button -- "refresh" indexes the archives that hasn't been indexed, while "delete" just removes the selected point (and its related entry in the dataset&db) on the chart.